# How to rotate a log file from crontab?

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have this directive on my crontab:

```
* * * * * /var/www/github/mysite/bin/email email worker await --pid=/var/run/mysite-worker-email.pid >> /tmp/mysite-worker-email.log
```

As you can see all my logs are written in */tmp/mysite-worker-email.log*, is there a way I can rotate that file?

Comment: @Sven My system is not doing any logrotate, im just dumping the echo of a php script on a file using crontab: * * * * * myscript >> log.txt

Comment: @DomingoSL the point is, the machine on which you are running your crontab entry probably does have logrotate installed.  You can use logrotate to rotate any logs, including your own, and it's probably the most standard solution.  Are you the sysadmin for this machine or is it shared hosting or something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming you have root permissions on the machine. If you are on shared hosting, SF is the wrong site for you anyway.

Check if `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d` exists. If they do, add a file with a fitting name, e.g. `site_email` into `/etc/logrotate.d` with a content like the following:

```
/tmp/mysite-worker-email.log {
   compress
   daily 
   missingok
   rotate 7
}
```

This will rotate the log files daily, and keep compressed copies of the last 7 days. `logrotate` has many more options, see `man logrotate.conf` for all of them.

Please note: Keeping log files in `/tmp` is a bad idea. Put them into `/var/log/` where they belong, especially if you want to keep more copies of the log file and don't want them to get deleted when `/tmp` is cleaned up.